# flask template not redirecting

Tags: python, flask, rendering

here is my flask app

```
@app.route("/inputs", methods=["POST"])
def inputs():
    file = request.files.get("dataset")
    algo = request.form.getlist("algo")
    
    if not file:
        return render_template("input_form.html", error="Please upload a CSV file", algos=ALGO, selected_algo=algo)
    
    data = io.StringIO(file.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    dataset = pd.read_csv(data)

    train_thread = Thread(target=train_models, args=(app, algo, dataset))
    train_thread.start()

    return render_template("loading.html")


def train_models(app, algo, dataset):
    print("Starting training...")
    with app.app_context():
        plot_model = Gen_Plot()
        plots = dict()
        selected_algo = dict()

        for model in algo:
            # code to train different models
  
        print("Rendering visualize.html with plots")
        return render_template("visualize.html")
```

I am trying to implement flask thread so that i can display a loading screen while the user waits until the models are being trained and evaluated. In this code the loading.html is getting rendered and the train_models def is also called, the results of the model(s) are generated but, visualize.html is not getting rendered. I am unable to figure out why is that happening

Comment: Just do the loading screen logic on the frontend in JS. You can make the loading screen appear as soon as the user submits the form, then when server is done processing it can serve `visualize.html` (move this into the `inputs` function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, even with an async function in Flask, the render_template will not be executed until the function completes.

Instead of returning render_template from that function, you can store the results in a global var and then draw from that. You can also check out Celery or Redis for background tasks, eg displaying loading progress https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-and-celery/

Comment: i tried storing variables in session, and even though i use app_context() it throws a runtime error of working outside context.